# Implement an Image Change when textview is changed

Tags: java, android

I am setting up a Click Counter android app.  The maximum count is 500, and the count is displayed in a TextView field.
I want to be able to display one image whilst the count is between 0-100, then another image when the count is between 101-400, and then the first image again between 401 - 500.
I am new to Java and have no idea how to set this up.  Here is my code so far:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;

public class wazeefa extends Activity {

//Count Button  
TextView txtCount;
Button btnCount;
int count = 0; 
Button wmute;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.wazeefa);

    //button sound
    final MediaPlayer mpButtonClick = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.countbutton);

    txtCount = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.wcount); 
    txtCount.setText(String.valueOf(count));
    btnCount = (Button)findViewById(R.id.wclick);   

    btnCount.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View V) {
           count++; 
           if (count > 500) 
               count = 0;
           txtCount.setText(String.valueOf(count));
           mpButtonClick.start(); 
        }});
    ;}
    }
```

The new code looks like this after David's/Shreya's suggestions:

```
public void onClick(View V) {
        ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageview);
           count++; 
           if (count > 500) count = 0;
           if (count < 1) image.setImageResource(R.drawable.duroodimage); 
           if (count > 0) image.setImageResource(R.drawable.duroodimage);
           if (count > 100) image.setImageResource(R.drawable.zikrimage); 
           if (count > 400) image.setImageResource(R.drawable.duroodimage);
           txtCount.setText(String.valueOf(count));
           mpButtonClick.start(); 
        }});
    ;}
```

But the images do not change when the relevant counts have been reached...

XML code for the ImageView:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Comment: Do you have an `ImageView` in your xml layout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the code to change image in the btnCount's onClickListener.

```
btnCount.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View V) {
        ImageView image = findViewById(...); // ... is the id of ImageView
        count++; 
        if (count > 500) count = 0;
        if (count > 100) image.setDrawable(...); // 100~200
        if (count > 200) image.setDrawable(...); // 200~300
        // ... and then 300~400 and 400~500
        txtCount.setText(String.valueOf(count));
        mpButtonClick.start(); 
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi David, I tried adding your suggestion, as you can see above.
But I get the following error:
- The method setDrawable(new View.OnClickListener(){}, int) is undefined for the type View

Comment: Oh, sorry. You need to change the `View image = findViewById...` to `ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById...`

Comment: @Mustafa Try image.setImageResource(R.drawable.myimagename);

Comment: @ShreyaShah and Hi,thanks for that that has got rid of the error!  However the 'image change' does not work when the clicks have reached the relevant totals...

Comment: I have added the XML for the ImageView

Comment: @Mustafa, you need to add your code to the *question*, not to the answer.

Comment: OK i ran it again and the Images are changing, Thanks so much to everyone!  However only one issue remaining, there is no image being displayed when the count is 0.  Any suggestions on how to fix this?